# How to convenient comment out if condition statement in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, comments

I am Python beginner, sometimes I would like to test my code without if condition statement like below picture

[image]

Since Python determines the level of code by indentation, I had to resize the indentation after commenting out the if statement.

And when I test passed, I have to resize the indentation to origin indentation before I open the if conditional statement comment.

This is an inconvenience compared to Java comment.

So is there any convenience skill that I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

Good question! Python has a `pass` statement that essentially does nothing. You can use it as a placeholder when you want to temporarily disable a block of code. It does not modify the indentation of anything.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34458672)

Answer (score -1):

You can remove spaces with SHIFT TAB

Comment: Yes, I know to do like Shift+Tab. But if I command out many levels of code by indentation,  I also have to Shift+Tab many correspond code. It's troublesome